# Recruiter changed mind

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I am using this fresh account, because my own is linked to my real name. Sorry.

I am not satisfied with my current job, so I have sent CV to a major software firm in my city. They responded, gave me test to do at home, so I did.
They asked me to interview, I passed it.
After that, they told me that they indeed want me as an employee, but not now. "Maybe in 1-3 months". Apparently they were under some heavy load.
But, suddenly, after 3 days, they changed mind. They want me *now*.

I haven't respond to the first email. Was it some kind of test I do not know about? Is it normal behaviour?

I live in Poland.

Comment: It's not at all unusual to need additional IT staff resources urgently - that's why the IT contract market exists.

Comment: Best of luck with it! Hope it goes well. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think it's a test. Things happen. Circumstances change. Their client might want the product sooner, a pregnant woman might stay home earlier or longer, someone might be sick for a longer time so they could use a replacement earlier, maybe someone else quit or maybe they just got their budget approved earlier through a bureaucratic miracle. Who knows. Plans change.

I would not interpret too much into it. It's not exactly "normal", it does not happen every time, but it's common enough to not worry about it.

Comment: I've personally seen this happen a few times for the reasons above (pregnancy and someone quitting).

Comment: _"maybe they just got their budget approved earlier through a bureaucratic miracle"_ - these miracles you speak of, to what deity shall one sacrifice the _____ (insert animal/thing) to appease the Gods of The String of the Purse?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I guess that would be the god of stamps & carbon copies in a pantheon of your choice :)

Answer (score 4):

Things change.  Maybe you were second choice and the first choice bailed/failed references/wanted too much.  Maybe they got the big contract they hoped but didn't expect.  Maybe the team mate you'd have worked with has suddenly quit so they need you to fill his shoes.  You can't say, but it happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good chance that your lack of communication with them worked out good for you.  While you heard that they might want you in 1-3 months the employer probably asked the recruiter how you responded.

When the employer hears the recruiter say, "He didn't respond."  The first thought that would come to mind from an employer could be, wow we have a candidate that passed all of our tests and looked really good, and now he has probably moved on to interview elsewhere.  So in their "oh-crap-mode" they shot an email to recruiter saying we would like the person as soon as possible.

Given the latest communications you have the upper hand in the process right now.  I would make sure you are getting a position that you brings you to your qualifications and money that you are happy with.

Comment: Sorry, this is bunkum, there is nothing to say that not communicating makes you more attractive to an employer.  As a hiring manager I'd just think "couldn't be bothered", but then I always feedback to interviewees so what do I know.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager - I find it odd that you downvote my answer because it is my opinion, then your feedback is your opinion then you answer with your opinion.  I have hired a lot of people.  I have definitely gone out of my way to push things faster if a candidate seems to not respond to a longer/further start date.

Comment: No, you've presented conjecture as fact - " I am sure the first thought that would come to mind from an employer is, wow we have a candidate that passed all of our tests and looked really good, and now he has probably moved on to interview elsewhere" there is no evidence of this.  I've just listed sensible reasons why the employer may have changed mind and wants to move more quickly, I didn't put words in their mouth

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager - Is this writing SE?  I think most people get the gist I wasn't speaking of an ultimate truth since there are very little answers that could fall in that category.  I will edit to make the answer more open.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in a recruiting process there may be several people involved form the employeer side, not just the recruiter (usually an employee from an internal Human Resources, or from a external Human Resources Company).

We are used to think recruiting as a single person choice, usually a Human Resources person, but, there may be other people taking decisions, on wheter recruiting or more.

I have personally experienced several "changes of mind", both positive or negative. Sometimes the recruiter discards me, and the department boss accepts me, or viceversa.

And, some people may change their mind.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what everyone else said.  Nothing suspicious sounding about this.  Besides why would it be a test - they are separate to your company?

The bottleneck that was preventing them from immediately moving forward went away for one reason or another.

3 main potential reasons:
1) they got more resources
2) they got more project work
3) unexpected decrease in worker supply